# CRM : Public Property - Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm

I am using Dynamics CRM 2013 On-Premise version.

I am writing the WCF service code for accessing the entity data for external System.

Below is the defined public property in the public class ApplicationDefinition.

```
  private Lookup _productType;
    public Lookup ProductType
    {
        get { return _productType; }
        set { _productType = value; }
    }
```

Lookup is one of the dictionary kind of datatype in CRM.

Now I want to set value for this ProductType but I am getting this error.

```
objApplicationDefinition.ProductType.Value = EntityExtension.GetString(entity, "producttypecode");



Getting Error :  Cannot modify the return value of 'CRM.ApplicationDefinition.ProductType' because it is not a variable.
```

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Thank you,
Mittal.

Comment: LookUp are EntityReference in CRM

Answer (score 0):

Lookup fields are EntityReference type

[Types in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328507.aspx)

You can set the field value as below:

```
entity["fieldname"] = new EntityReference("entityname", guid);
```